# Where are old install files coming from?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I'm using VS.NET 2010.  My solution has both a winforms and setup projects.  The solution is fairly old.  I've done a new compile and have run the MSI.  It installs everything fine but the EXE and config file that get installed are dated from 2011.  I don't know where these files are coming from.  Since I just compiled both projects, the EXE and config files in the project folders have current dates.

Where do I look to find out where the setup project is getting these older files from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to define "it installs everything fine" because clearly it doesn't. I suspect that you just rebuilt the MSI file and didn't use RemovePreviousVersions. Or even if you did use RPV, you didn't increment the file versions of the versioned files. It's versions that matter with versioned files, not dates. If your binaries don't have versions you need to add them.

This still applies, with the extra step that you must increment file versions now.

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/